# blazor serverside console.writeline font work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, single-page-application, blazor-server-side

how can log in result in blazor sever side
console.write in server side blazor dont work

<button @onclick=@(()=> Console.WriteLine("show log") )>show2

```
    @code{
        public void show() => Console.Write("show log2");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the log in `Output` window which is from ASP.NET Core Web Server:

[image]

Note:

To open the `Output` window, on the menu bar, choose **View** > **Output**, or press **Ctrl**+**Alt**+**O**.